# How to use github cli to auto pull all newly created or updated repos to local pc

Tags: github, github-cli

How to use github cli to auto pull all newly created or updated repos to local pc?

I think I need to listen for new repo creation/updation and pull the repos. How to do it with cli?

If can't listen, I need to pull latest 100 repos to local machiene. How to do it?

I tried `https://api.github.com/users/xxxx/repos?per_page=100`. It gives in alphabetical order.

I use following code

```
 #!/bin/sh                                                                       
    cat repolist.txt | while read line                                              
     do                                                                              
     REPOSRC=$line                                                                   
     LOCALREPO=$line                                                                 
                                                                                     
     # We do it this way so that we can abstract if from just git later on           
     LOCALREPO_VC_DIR=$LOCALREPO/.git                                                
                                                                                     
     if [ ! -d $LOCALREPO_VC_DIR ]                                                   
    then                                                                            
       cd ~/xxxx                                                                
       gh repo clone $REPOSRC                                                       
       cd ~                                                                         
    else                                                                            
       cd ~                                                                         
       gh repo sync $REPOSRC -s $REPOSRC                                            
    fi                                                                              
    done                                                                            
    # End
```

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've written so far, even if it does not yet retrieve the desired repos properly.

Comment: updated with code. How to listen to new addition/updation of repo? Or is there any autosync feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sort key](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28)
you're looking for seems to be `sort=pushed`.

Try `curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/xxxx/repos?sort=pushed&per_page=100' | jq '.[].name'` to verify.

Comment: Thanks, any way to detect new creation/updation in my github repos(some other employees also able to create/update my repos)

Comment: Sothat I can clone/sync only those repos

Comment: That is a new question @bsde 

Comment: I asked in first post

Comment: Just say if possible or not so that I can creat next post